# How to handle Trello webhooks? RoR API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, webhooks, rails-api

I am new at backend developing (RoR). Sorry for my English.

Now I am working with Trello API and trying to receive (handle) webhooks.
I'm using ruby-trello gem. Also I'm using ngrok.

I successfully created webhooks (in Trello).
Now when I edit Trello object (marked by webhook), I have the request from Trello to my app to WebhooksController#receive.

routes.rb:

```
  post '/webhooks' => 'webhooks#receive', :defaults => { :format => 'json' }
  get '/webhooks' => 'webhooks#complete', :defaults => { :format => 'json' }
```

webhooks_controller.rb

```
class WebhooksController < ApplicationController

  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  @@data = File.read('public/data.json')

  def complete
    render status: 200
  end

  def receive
    JSON.parse(request.body.read)
    render :json => @@data
  end

end
```

But all the time I see `JSON::ParserError (765: unexpected token at ''):`

Now **I just want to see webhooks request's json** for understanding and code next steps.

Can anyone help please?
Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: Why did you bind two hooks to single method? I'd use separate methods in controller for each hook. Probably when you receive POST request it sends you JSON, but GET requests asks you for something and it sends empty body you're trying to parse.

Comment: Question was about only GET requests. Now I have edited my code (also edit question). When I have GET request to webhooks#complete, I see this error:
``Started HEAD "/webhooks" for 107.23.149.70 at 2019-05-07 13:05:03 +0300
E, [2019-05-07T13:05:13.885650 #15661] ERROR -- : [400 POST https://api.trello.com/1/webhooks]: {"message":"URL (https://*******.ngrok.io/webhooks) not reachable. Error: ESOCKETTIMEDOUT","error":"ERROR"}``

Comment: It looks like Trello cannot connect to the endpoint you have specified `https://*******.ngrok.io/webhooks`.

Comment: @neversleep I am not so stupid. I intentionally hid a really used ip for question, not for app)

Comment: I'm talking about the error **URL (...) not reachable**, **ESOCKETTIMEDOUT**. Whatever endpoint you've specified Trello cannot connect to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can log what is coming from webhook request's JSON using `logger.info`.

For example:

```
def receive
  logger.info "Trello webhook request's JSON: #{params}"
  # rest of your code...
end
```

Then you have to check your logs. Probably it will be in `log/production.log`.

If you are able to make Trello hit your local server, you can debug your action to see what is in the webhook request's JSON putting a `debugger` statement in the action.

For example:

```
def receive
  debugger
  JSON.parse(request.body.read)
  render :json => @@data
end
```

Also, `request.body.read` is not the best way to get your params. You can just call `params` and it will return a `Hash` with your params. Actually, `request.body.read` does not return an object in a valid format to be parsed to JSON, I think that is the cause of the exception.